# Setting time zone when passing oracle.sql.ARRAY to PL/SQL procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm calling a `plsql package procedure` from Java. This procedure has an type parameter which carries a `timestamp`. When I'm setting a timestamp parameter directly to a procedure I can specify a `Calendar object` to declare the time zone to use e. g.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
statement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis()), calendar);
```

Is there a way to declare a timezone when using an `oracle.sql.ARRAY` or `oracle.sql.STRUCT` ?

The used types are declared as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_EVENT_OBJECT"
AS
OBJECT
(
timestamp_event              date,
state                        number(15),
parameter_name               varchar2(248),
value                        number(15)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_EVENTS"
AS
TABLE OF TY_EVENT_OBJECT;
```

The Type TY_EVENTS is one parameter of the plsql procedure i have to use.

Comment: What DB data type is your array, a table or varray of `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP`? Why can't you populate each element of the matching Java collection the same way?

Comment: @AlexPoole it is no collection of timestamps, it is an object type. Your second question I don't understand, the plsql api we are using needs to call this plsql api.

Comment: Well are you passing an array of those objects, or a single object? Showing the procedure specification and the Java code that calls it might make things a bit clearer (for me, anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simply pass a calendar which will be used for time zone conversion when you use user defined oracle types. When oracle.sql.ARRAY and oracle.sql.STRUCT are used, the ojdbc uses local calendar to convert java.sql.Date to oracle.sql.DATE so the actual date stored in database, in your case, is local time without timezone. 
So if you want the date to be stored to database in UTC you will have to convert the java.sql.Date to oracle.sql.DATE manually by using UTC calendar. 
Here is how you could do it:

1. Implement the SQLData interface and override the methods. 
   **note:**
   -getSQLTypeName has to return the actual type name as defined in database, otherwise doesn't work. 
   -we use java.sql.Date below, it's important. So, if you want java.util.Date outside of TyEventObject you could create a setter/getter that does the conversion

   ```
   public class TyEventObject implements SQLData {

     private String sqlTypeName = "TY_EVENT_OBJECT";
     private java.sql.Date timestampEvent;
     private long state;
     private String parameterName;
     private long value;

     @Override
     public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
       return sqlTypeName;
     }

     @Override
     public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
       sqlTypeName = typeName;

       // Reading date in UTC time 
       OracleJdbc2SQLInput oracleStream = (OracleJdbc2SQLInput) stream;
       DATE oracleDate = (DATE)oracleStream.readOracleObject();
       if( oracleDate != null) {
         timestampEvent = oracleDate.dateValue( Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
       } else {
         timestampEvent = null;
       }

       state = stream.readLong();
       parameterName = stream.readString();
       value = stream.readLong();
     }

     @Override
     public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
       // Writing timestamp in UTC time 
       OracleSQLOutput oracleStream = (OracleSQLOutput) stream;
       if( timestampEvent != null) {
         DATE oracleDate = new DATE( timestampEvent, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
         oracleStream.writeOracleObject( oracleDate);
       } else {
         stream.writeDate( null);
       }
       stream.writeLong( state);
       stream.writeString( parameterName);
       stream.writeLong( value);
     }

   // add public getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. Now you create an array of these TyEventObject objects to pass to plsql procedure like this (note that Array is java.sql.Array):

   ```
   // I assume that your event objects that you want to save are in the list eventObjects
   TyEventObject[] entries = new TyEventObject[ eventObjects.size()];
   for( int i=0; i < eventObjects.size(); i++) {
     entries[i] = new TyEventObject();
     // You set the properties here
     // entries[i].setTimestampEvent( eventObjects.get( i).getTimestampEvent());
   }

   Array dataObjectArray = connection.createArrayOf( "TY_EVENTS", entries);
   ```
3. And finally you call you plsql procedure like usual:

   ```
   CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call ProcedureName( ?)}");
   cs.setObject(1, dataObjectArray, Types.ARRAY);
   cs.execute(); 
   cs.close();
   ```